# Issues while adding multiple O365 email accounts in Third Party Application

Tags: oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft365

I am trying to add multiple email address into a third part application like Outlook. For first email id, after entering email address, it's opening a WebView implemented windows asks for password. But for second email address, it does not open password window in webview and trying to authenticate automatically.

How can fix this behavior?